# How to find n in $n^3 > 3n^2 -100n +6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality

I tried by removing constant 6 to simplify my work:

$n^3>3n^2-100n$

$1> 3/n - 100/n^2 $

$n>3-100/n$

and then $ n + 100/n > 3$

I am stuck here any help, is there any standard way to find n from above equality.

Comment: Are you trying to find only one such $n$ or the whole solution set?

Comment: @Sobi Just such an $n$ that satisfies  the inequality

Comment: Well in that case $n=1$ is an obvious solution.

Comment: @Sobi Sorry if I confuses you, my professor said $n>3$ is the answer for that, so I am trying to figure out why only $n>3$

Comment: Removing the constant +6 may rule out potential solutions, and you may end up finding non-solutions that satisfy $n^3>3n^2-100n$ but not $n^3>3n^2-100n +6$.  $n$, I take it, is being used to represent a natural number.  Hence dividing by a natural number n which is cubed: i.e., dividing by $n^3$ may yield non-integers, which will likely rule out potential solutions.  What you can do is, assuming $n \in \mathbb N$, where $n \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of manipulations which might help.

The first would be to make both sides positive, so to write the inequality as $$n^3+100n\gt 3n^2+6$$ now that becomes $$n(n^2+100)\gt 3n^2+6$$

Now this is obviously true whenever $n\ge 3$ because $3n^2+300\gt 3n^2+6$ and there are other cases to investigate.

Another would be to adjust to give a convenient factorisation on the right-hand side, something like $$n^3+91n\gt 3n^2-9n+6=3(n-1)(n-2)$$

Or you could make the left-hand side factor conveniently eg $$n^3+20n^2+100n\gt23n^2+6$$ with $$n(n+10)^2\gt 23n^2+6$$

I will leave you to explore the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Set $f(x) = x^3 - 3x^2 + 100x - 6$, then
$f'(x) = 3x^2 - 6x + 100$.

Its not hard to show that $f'(x) > 0 \ \forall x$

Now the inequality isnt true for $n=0$ but it is true for $n=1$ and hence true $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ (Starting at $1$)

Comment: Using calculus for the level at which the OP has classified the problem (algebra-precalculus) is a bit presumptuous of you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what is taught in pre-calc around the world. But this was something that was taught at my first year in High-school. Calculus wasnt studied until 3 years later. @amWhy